# How to center object in a slider

Tags: html, css

I have a demonstation here: [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text44.php)

You should be able to see audio players displayed in a slider. The issue I am having is that I do not know how to center the audio player into the middle of slider. How can this be acheived and I want this working in all browsers:

Below is code displaying slider and an iframe which links to the audio player itself:

```
<style>
    #galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 550px; height: 200px; background: #000; }
</style>

 <div id="galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>">
<?php
foreach ($arrAudioFile[$key] as $a) { ?>

<a href="audio.php?key=<?php echo $key; ?>&j=<?php echo $j; ?>&a=<?php echo $a; ?>"><img class="iframe" src="Images/audiothumbnail.png"></a>

<?php $j++; ?>
<?php } ?>
</div><br/>

         <script type="text/javascript">

            Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run('#galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>');

          </script> 

    <?php


}
```

I am using Galleria as my slider and documentation could be found here if you want to see: http://galleria.io/docs/

MORE INFORMATION:

I only want audio players in the slider to be centred in the slider.

Below is full code where if there is no audio then it displays a blank, if there is one audio then display single audio player on page (that is most of the code below), if multiple audio players then display in slder. This is for each questions even though I have not included the loop for each question in code snippet below:

```
        //start:procedure audio
        $aud_result = '';
        if(empty($arrAudioFile[$key])){
          $aud_result = '&nbsp;';
        }else{

$j = 0;
if(count($arrAudioFile[$key]) == 1){
foreach ($arrAudioFile[$key] as $a) { 

        $info = pathinfo('AudioFiles/'.$a); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#jquery_jplayer-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
      $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { 
          $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        });
    },
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_interface_<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>",
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
});
}); 
</script>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface" id="jp_interface_<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-time-holder">
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <ul class="jp-toggles">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
}else if(count($arrAudioFile[$key]) > 1){

    ?>

<style>
    #galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 550px; height: 200px; background: #000; margin:0; }
</style>

 <div id="galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>">
<?php
foreach ($arrAudioFile[$key] as $a) { ?>

<a href="audio.php?key=<?php echo $key; ?>&j=<?php echo $j; ?>&a=<?php echo $a; ?>"><img class="iframe" src="Images/audiothumbnail.png"></a>

<?php $j++; ?>
<?php } ?>
</div><br/>

         <script type="text/javascript">

            Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run('#galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>');

          </script> 

    <?php

}

}
//end:procedure audio
```

Comment: Add margin to the below mentioned class...

div.jp-audio, div.jp-audio-stream, div.jp-video{margin:0 auto !important;}

Comment: @Gopikrishna can  Iquickly state that I have single audio player not displayed in slider and multiple audio players displayed in slider. I only want the multiple audio players in slider to be centered in the slider only. If I do what you just commented, would that just not cause all audio players to be centered?

Comment: @Gopikrishna You code only works for the single audip players not displayed in slider

Comment: @Gopikrishna Look at more information on question.

Answer (score 0):

You can center by adding `margin: 0 auto` to the element you want to center.

```
.jp-audio {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Please note that this only works if the element is a block element and has a set width.

Comment: Can you look at comment above I made to Gopikrishna, I only want audio players in slider to be centered

Comment: You code only works for the single audip players not displayed in slider

Answer (score 0):

Apply these styles, It should work

```
div.jp-audio {
margin: auto !important;
width: 85% !important;
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't that do it for all audio players, I only want this to happen to audio players in slider only. Can I add you css to the style tag I have, because I have an if statment so I can mention in style to perform the above in the if statement so that only audio players in slider will be changed

Comment: You code only works for the single audip players not displayed in slider

Comment: Yeah but as I mentioned you code does it only for the audio players not in the sliders only. I want it to happen to the audio players in the slider only